# Auto-Correlation

Tags: r, autocorrelation, randomness

I had thought that if I call acf() on a vector of integers, and examine the value correlation coefficient at K (lag) = 1, I would expect:

- A value close to +/-1 would show that the integers are not random at
  all
- A value close to 0 would show that the sequence is pretty much random

I have called the acf function on sequences that are ***very*** ***un-random***, and the above premise does NOT hold.

I am learning about acf, and it is interesting, but I don’t necessarily see how it can prove show that a sequence of integers is close to random.

Is it important to choose the correct lag value?

Any and all advice/pointers very much appreciated.

Comment: One way to start appreciating the difference between randomness and lack of correlation would be to consider a sequence formed from random integers (symmetrically distributed around a zero mean) by inserting a $0$ between each pair. The acf will be $0$ at all lags but the new sequence is obviously far from random!

Comment: 1) A large value of the first order autocorrelation implies that the observations are highly correlated with the immediately previous observations. But autocorrelation may arise at other lag orders, e.g., every four observations (the value observed today is influenced by the value observed 4 periods before). 2) The R package [randtests](http://cran.r-project.org/package=randtests) provides some non parametric tests for randomness, you may find some useful examples and tools there. 3) As in the example given by whuber, there may be other sources of non-randomness apart from linear correlation.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, that is very helpful and useful.